# Highlight the search text after searching in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Hi can anyone help me how text can be highlighted after search, i want to search data from sqlite database and display it in a UITableView, so how i can highlight the search keyword only in the search Result?
Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:
Create a custom cell, and a view in that cell, to include the text.
You will need to use core text to be able to change the parts of background/text color from your string.
Upon your search, change the color/background color of text in drawRect method.

Please see [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text) for more about Core Text.

Comment: thanks for your help but i m new to ios development, so please can you send me other tutorial link, actually i want to search data from database which is will working but when search return and display in a uitableview so then i want to highlight search keyword, is there any easy tutorial for that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Is searching the database working correctly? How about displaying search results in UITableView? When you do all that, you can proceed to the next step which is highlighting text in the table cells.

Comment: Yes you'r right but tutorial that you provide is very complex and i m very new to ios so that's why i m feeling hard to do the last step how i can use CoreText here for displaying highlight on text? Thanks for your response

Comment: Since this is getting more into CoreText, please start a new question and post some code with the exact issue you are having. But basically, you will need two NSString @property objects in your UIView subclass, one with the whole text, and the other for the text in your search. In drawRect method, draw the whole text in a black background, and a yellow background for your search text.

Comment: You can change these colors using:     NSDictionary* attrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                           (id)self.color.CGColor, kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, (id)fontRef, kCTFontAttributeName, (id)self.strokeColor.CGColor, (NSString *) kCTStrokeColorAttributeName,(id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat: self.strokeWidth], (NSString *)kCTStrokeWidthAttributeName,                        nil];
    [aString appendAttributedString:[[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[parts objectAtIndex:0] attributes:attrs] autorelease]];

Comment: `myCustomCell *Customcell = (myCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customIdentifier];
    if (Customcell == nil) {
        Customcell = [[[myCustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:customIdentifier] autorelease];
    }            Customcell.charName.text = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
`

Comment: this is my code where i want to display the search text i have made a custom cell with label charName and i m assigning return value here to the custom cell. so how i can use NSAttributedString with that? thanks in Advance for your help